# to be a bit more together

Tags: grammar, expressions

Is this sentence grammatical?

**You'll have to be a bit more together when you have kids.**

..................................

Together : Being a 'together' person can mean having well-organised ideas, or being sensible and confident, usually used in the negative sense.
"He's not very together."
"Get it together, man."

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=together
......................................................................................

10. Informal. emotionally stable and well organized: a very together person.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/together

Comment: Is there some particular aspect of the sentence that makes you doubt its grammaticality? If so, what is it?

Comment: @Erik It's just : a "bit more" together

Answer (score 1):

Robert Chapman & Barnara Kipfer, *Dictionary of American Slang* (1995) has this entry for the source phrase "get it together":

> **get it together** (or **all together**) ***v phr*** (Variations: one's **act** or one's **head** or one's **shit** or one's **stuff** may replace **it**) *1960s counterculture fr black* To arrange one's life or affairs properly; integrate and focus oneself [examples omitted]

The OP's two online references suggest much the same meaning.

There is nothing ungrammatical about the sentence "You'll have to be a bit more together when you have kids." But nonfluent English speakers need to be aware that the meaning shifts sharply if you move "a bit more" so that it falls after "together." The original wording,

> You'll have to be a bit more together when you have kids.

is a warning that the person being spoken to will have to behave more responsibly and methodically once children enter the picture. In contrast,

> You'll have to be together a bit more when you have kids.

sounds more than anything else like a warning to two people that they won't be free to go their own separate ways as much when they have children. Instead, they'll have to spend a bit more time together.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of "together" as an adjective is a grammatical use.  To me, it sounds dated, circa mid-1970s.  The full idiom was "got your/his shit together".  You need to be aware that many people will remember the full phrase.  You reinforced your informal tone by using "kids" instead of children.

I had heard "together" used as primarily positive. *She's got it all together.*

There's also a joke dating back to about 1975: "I finally got it all together, now I forgot where I put it."